# Variable value changes when used in different files

Tags: javascript, random

I have a random variable and alert this variable in one JavaScript file, then do some process with the same value of the random variable in another HTML file. However, it seems that two variable shows different value in two files when I used `alert()` function to inspect the results in two files. **What I want to achieve is to have the variable with same value to be consistent in the process**.

In JavaScript file, the related code to generate random variable `RandomMsg` values and alert the random variable `Random_Msg`:

```
function CreateRandomMsg() {
    var RandomMsg = Msgs_Arr[Math.floor(Math.random()* Msgs_Arr.length)];
    return RandomMsg;
}

var Random_Msg = CreateRandomMsg();

function alertMsg() {
    alert(Random_Msg);
}
```

In HTML file, I include this JavaScript file and just use the random variable `Random_Msg`, however it shows a different message value from the message alerts to users in the JavaScript file. I'm not sure which part of the code contains mistake.

Comment: "it shows a different message value" --- different comparing to *what*?

Comment: Of course it will be different each time you load a page with this script in it. What is the question or what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @zerkms just edited the question, different from the value in the JavaScript file.

Comment: @charlietfl I want to display a same value.

Comment: If you want to display the same value - return the same value.

Comment: You need to store that value somewhere...there is no persistence in javascript between pages

Comment: @charlietfl How about use local storage to store it?

Comment: sure...that would work fine

Comment: @charlietfl okay! I will try first and get back here.

Answer (score 0):

```js
Msgs_Arr =["some","messages","here"]
function CreateRandomMsg() {
    var RandomMsg = Msgs_Arr[Math.floor(Math.random()* Msgs_Arr.length)];
    return RandomMsg;
}

var Random_Msg = CreateRandomMsg();

function alertMsg() {
    alert(Random_Msg);
}

alertMsg();
document.getElementById("message").text= Random_Msg;
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <a id="message"></a>
  </body>

</html>
```

Are you trying to do something like this?
Be sure that you are'nt calling CreateRandomMsg twice or more

Comment: Yes, the difference is I'm trying to pass the variable as a value so that I could continue the process, I used local storage to save the variable, but it's value still changes when used in HTML file.

Comment: i guess that you're running the function which writes in local storage every time a page loaded.
Try to check it and avoid to write if its already set.